# How do I position a button to a canvas, not to the screen using Tkinter 3

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a canvas with an image I'd like to use for a background. My problem is that when I position the button to the correct place, and I try to scroll down, the button moves with the screen instead of staying where I want it to on the canvas.

```py
frame = Frame(self)
frame.pack()

mapImg = PhotoImage(file='Fo4-pip-map.png')
canvas = Canvas(frame, width=2048, height=2048, scrollregion=(0,0,2048,2048))
canvas.create_image(0,0, image=mapImg, anchor='nw')
canvas.image = mapImg

xscrollbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
xscrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X, anchor='s')
yscrollbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient=VERTICAL)
yscrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y, anchor='e')
xscrollbar.config(command=canvas.xview)
yscrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)

canvas.config(xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set, yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)
canvas.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=BOTH)


vaultImg = PhotoImage(file='Vault.png')
vaultImg = vaultImg.zoom(5)
vaultImg = vaultImg.subsample(32)

vault111Button = Button(canvas, width=30, height=30, borderwidth=0, image=vaultImg,
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame('Vault111'))
vault111Button.image = vaultImg
vault111Button.place(x=150, y=100)
```

Comment: your indentation is slightly broken.

Comment: @BryanOakley did I fix it? if you meant the first line I just pasted it incorrectly. The entire thing is in the same indentation.

Comment: yes, you fixed it, if it looks the same in your editor and in the actual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `place` geometry manager places children at a fixed offset from their parent - in particular, the scrolling of a canvas doesn't apply to them.  Get rid of that last line, and instead use:

```
canvas.create_window(150, 100, window=vault111Button)
```